# Create Opportunity in Dynamics CRM 365 from Partner Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, dotliquid, adxstudio-portals

I need to create a new Opportunity from the Dynamics CRM Partner Portal via a custom button.  The company sells software with a server that holds license details from each customer.  On the Customer page I have a link that links to a new page that shows the license details for the Customer (fetched from the License Server via REST).  I now need to use this licence details and create a new Opportunity for the Customer via the Portal.

[image: This is the OOB account entity form with an added link to view the license]
The above image is the OOB Customer entity form with an added link to view licence. 
From the next image an Opportunity should be created with Opportunity Products as specified on the page.  A01, A03 etc.

[image: Licence page]

I am using MS Dynamics v8.2

Comment: are you having any issue to use javascript/liquid to call crm web api for creating opportunity..?

Comment: Arun, From what I understand I can only do GET from liquid script using Fetch XML.  I am running into CORS issues when calling the REST api from Javascript.  I also prefer not to execute POST calls via JavaScript.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Adding my 2 cents,

I think you cannot directly call Post calls as of now to CRM API.

[Link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Portals/Call-CDS-rest-API-from-PowerApps-Portal/td-p/456848) stating same.

If you can tweak your process slightly a bit.

create a form or something and on save of record, fire workflow in crm which can be custom workflow and that custom workflow will take care of creating/updating opportunity with products.

[Here is an article giving some Idea.](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics212/posts/how-to-call-webapi-from-powerplatform-tag-portals)